# Customizing django logger call levels using filters

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm new to Django and I've been assign to do a task about loggers.
I have in mind a simple logger where INFO messages use a simple format and WARNING messages (and above) use a more complex one. This was my attempt:

```
    LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname}: {message} Time: [{asctime}] Module: [{module}] Process: [{process:d}] Thread: [{thread:d}] ',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_simple': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'level': 'INFO'
        },
        'console_verbose': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'level': 'WARNING'
        }
    },
    'loggers':{
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console_simple'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        }
    }
}
```

As you can problably imagine, the problem is that WARNING messages or higher will be **logged twice**. I've though about using filters, but I couldn't find any undestandable explanation on the documentation.

I've found the filter below on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234074/django-logger-is-mixing-between-levels-error-and-info):

```
import logging

class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.level == logging.INFO
```

The problem is that I don't know how to properly use it. I've never used filters before.

The [Django logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/) has the following example:

```
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
```

Where they say that:

> Defines two filters:
> project.logging.SpecialFilter, using the alias special. If this filter required additional arguments, they can be provided as additional keys in the filter configuration dictionary. In this case, the argument **foo** will be given a value of **bar** when instantiating SpecialFilter.

So, I believe that I need to give a value to logging.Filter the same way was "foo" received a value of "bar". The problem is that I have no idea on how to do that.

Am I at least on the right path? How can I use this filter? There are any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](https://djangocircle.com/how-to-create-different-custom-logs-formatter-for-info-warning-and-error-logs-in-django-web-application/)

you need to put a list in the filters indicating which levels they apply to.

Comment: Try to avoid a pure link answer, the link can expire

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30147534)